# Cheerio how to select individual items with same id

Tags: cheerio

Sorry if this is really simple...

```
$('#product-details dd').each((i, el) => {
  const title = $(el).text()
    console.log(title);
```

the page im scraping has 12 `<dd>` tags but i only want the first 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice:

```
$('#product-details dd').get().slice(0,7),map(dd => $(dd).text())
```